# How to append multiple .mat files that have the same variable names in them?

Tags: matlab, variables, save, load, mat

I run my scripts which produce hundreds or thousands of .mat files. Each of this file contains two variables: resultsU and resultsT. I want to append the files but not overwrite the variables. What is the easiest way to do so in Matlab? Some suggest manual manipulation of the .mat file which is not easy or efficient to do when you have hundreds of .mat files.

Comment: Imagine you have three such files. You would like to end up with a new .mat file with... six variables? Named how? Or perhaps a size-three struct with two fields? Or...?

Comment: [This may helps](http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/125602-concatenating-several-mat-file-into-one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rayryeng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31007298/3372061) is good if running the code which created the files is an option. However, if working with a huge amount of files is a given fact which you need to deal with, I would suggest to go about this using and array of `structs` (which resembles [`struct` concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/concatenate-structures.html)).

Consider the following example function:

```
function combined_results = CombineMat(newFolder)

oldFolder = cd; %// Backup the current directory
cd(newFolder);  %// Switch to some new folder
fList = dir('*.mat'); fList = {fList.name}'; %'// Get the file list

%% // Processing the list of files:
if isempty(fList), combined_results = []; return, end %// Check that some files exist

%// Initialize the result struct by loading the last file (also preallocates the struct):
nFiles = size(fList,1);
combined_results(nFiles) = load(fullfile(newFolder,fList{1}));

%// See if there is only 1 file, and return if so:
if nFiles == 1, return, end

%// Process any additional files 
for ind1 = 1:nFiles-1
    combined_results(ind1) = load(fullfile(newFolder,fList{ind1}));
end

%% Cleanup - changing the current directory back:
cd(oldFolder);
```

What it does is to combine `.mat` files containing the same variable names. Now you can run `combined_results = CombineMat(folder_with_mat_files)` and get a `struct` which contains all the different results (assuming you have enough memory to hold them). After you have this `struct` in memory, you can save it to a single `.mat` file.

Note 1: If you don't have enough memory to load all the files, you can add another piece of code to `CombineMat` that dumps `combined_results` to disk and clears it after a certain amount of loop iterations (possibly with the `'-append'` option as suggested by **rayryeng**. This personally doesn't make sense to me if [OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory) happens, because then you would have problems loading the resulting file :)

Note 2: Obviously, if you want your result as something other than an array of `structs`, the code needs to be modified accordingly.

---

In a more general case, where you are trying to concatenate structures with different variable names, you can use the [following FEX submission](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7842-catstruct) (which I can recommend from personal experience!).

---

**P.S.** My code was written on MATLAB 2015a.

Comment: resultsU and resultsT are the only variable names i use. But for each run of the file i have a different .mat file. Say, my file name is dosomething(a,b,c).m . I run dosomething for 1000 times with different a,b,c. The ouput is always stored in resultsU and resultsT, in a unique .mat file

Comment: shouldnt `combined_results(ind1) = load(fullfile(newFolder,fList{1}));`  be `combined_results(ind1) = load(fullfile(newFolder,fList{ind1}));` instead?

Answer (score 1):

It's actually a lot easier than you think.  If you want to append to MAT files, simply use [`save`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/save.html?refresh=true#bt0xgur-6) with the `-append` flag.  Assuming that you have a few variables... let's call them `p` and `q`, and assuming you have a file called `test.mat`, it's very simply:

```
save('test.mat','p','q','-append');
```

The beauty of this is that you don't need to load any of the variables in the MAT file and resave them with the appended variables.  This appends the desired variables into the MAT file without you ever having to load them into MATLAB.

If you have a bunch of `.mat` files in a directory, you can do something like this:

```
folder = '...'; %// Place directory here
f = dir(folder); %// Find files

%// For each file...
for idx = 1 : numel(f)
    name = fullfile(folder, f(idx).name); %// Get path to file

    %// Do some processing
    %//...
    %//

    %// Append to file
    save(name, ..., ..., ..., ..., '-append');
end
```

What goes inside the `...` for `save` are the variables you want to append to each file.

Comment: But doesn't this overwrite variables with the same name?

Comment: @LuisMendo - Yes it does!  The OP wasn't quite clear on that.  I'm assuming that the variables to append would be unique.  This statement is a bit unclear to me: _"I want to append the files but not overwrite the variables"_... how would you interpret it Luis?  To me it sounds like the OP wants to add more variables to the file, but keep the others in each MAT file untouched.... I'm actually not sure!

Comment: "_Each of this file contains two variables: resultsU and resultsT. I want to append the files but not overwrite the variables_": so I assume they are same-name variables

Comment: So would they want to add more data to `resultsU` and `resultsT`? :S? #mentalist

Comment: Hahaha. My guess is: change variable names. But the easiest would be to use a struct with two fields. Then you could use `s = load('filename')` to get those variables as fields, and then build a non-scalar `struct` with a size equal to the number of files

Comment: @LuisMendo - I'll wait until the OP clarifies because I actually have no idea what they want now lol.  If it turns out to be how you interpreted, I'll delete my answer to leave room for you to answer the question.

Comment: No, really, if you feel like writing the answer in that case, please go ahead. I won't probably take the time for that anyway :-)

Comment: resultsU and resultsT are the only variable names i use. But for each run of the file i have a different .mat file. Say, my file name is dosomething(a,b,c).m . I run dosomething for 1000 times with different a,b,c. The ouput is always stored in resultsU and resultsT, in a unique .mat file

Comment: @JustCurious - Took you long enough to reply lol.  I lost interest in your question so I hope that someone else will answer it.  Perhaps look at Dev-IL's answer.  Good luck!